# Logging in with Facebook: Does the getAccessToken() function has arguments?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to understand how to use facebook to allow log in of users into my website.

I do get the authentication of the website ok, but the page gets blank after the user authorizes the app.

Here's what I've got:

### The log in page:

```
session_start();
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/autoload.php' );

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'xxx',
  'app_secret' => 'xxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

// Requested permissions - optional
$permissions = array(
  'email',
  'user_location',
  'user_birthday'
);

// Get login URL
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://www.learning.online/facebook/demofbcallback.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

### The callback:

```
session_start();

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/autoload.php' );

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'xxx',
  'app_secret' => 'xxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
]);  

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

var_dump($accessToken);
```

### I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function
>   Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper::getAccessToken(), 0
>   passed in /home/learning/public_html/facebook/demofbcallback.php on
>   line 18 and at least 1 expected in
>   /home/learning/public_html/facebook/facebook/src/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php:280
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/learning/public_html/facebook/demofbcallback.php(18):
>   Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper->getAccessToken() #1
>   {main} thrown in
>   /home/learning/public_html/facebook/facebook/src/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php
>   on line 280

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of the Facebook PHP SDK are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm using v5.0

Comment: The method takes the redirect URI as optional parameter, but it should not be mandatory. It is weird though that the error message says line 280, because that line should be just the closing `}` of a short `if` block, https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/5.x/src/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php#L280